# where they are set the variables in the smarty document used by prestashop

Tags: web, content-management-system, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

for example the variable $category.name where it is set from? I cant find it in the back office.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzO5y.png)

Answer (score 0):

controllers\front\listing\CategoryController.php

For any variable please follow `$this->context->smarty->assign` in front or admin controller